Has Google given up the Condensed variant of the Noto Sans Mono font?
I am currently searching for a condensed mono sans serif font. Since I use the Noto Sans font family quite often, I was glad to find a font named "Noto Sans Mono Condensed" on this page. But then I noticed that Google does not offer this font variant (any more?).
This raises the question where download sites get this font from. Is it possibly a (low-quality) variant that they have hacked themselves, or is it an old version that Google offered in ancient times, or is it just the current Noto Sans font that Google offers, but where the width is reduced (the latter would be possible without loss of quality because the version that Google offers is variable in two axes, where the lowest possible width percentage seems to be about 63%).

I'm voting to close this because I can't possibly fathom how anyone here would have any answers to any of this. It's all speculative. It would require a Google employee involved in Google Fonts to even guess.

It's OK to close, I already was aware that this could happen. I guess I'll delete the question then.

The only thing I could find online about this font is that it appears in a project called "Go Noto" on Github. https://github.com/gonoto/gonoto. It says it's a third party project, nothing to do with Google. There's no information about who made it originally.

@BillyKerr Thank you very much for your time! Too bad that they chose such a misleading name then.

@Scott Now that there is an answer to the question, I'd like to ask you to retract your close vote. I believe that the question and its answer will be useful for other visitors. Obviously, the original (Google) Noto Mono Condensed is extremely hard to find although Google has not abandoned it. I have put several hours into searching it and only found clones at questionable places. That's an exemplary case where a question that's considered speculative even by experts finally is answered. In fact, I was hoping that this would happen before the question gets closed :-)

Yes, on the Github page there's a link to a page with all the Noto releases. It says it has Noto Mono in condensed weight as well as semi-condensed and extra-condensed.

Thank you very much for your answer! I have put several hours into searching that font, but missed that page. Of course, accepted and +1.
